# How do I avoid copying 3rd party C++ dlls?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, path, app-config

I have a solution with a C++ project and a c# project, which calls methods from the first one using Interop.
As I want to avoid any hard-coded path, I found a way to set the C++ dll's path in the app.config.
My problem is, that my C++ dll depends on other dlls, which I always have to copy into my bin/Release and bin/Debug folder. How can I avoid this?
It would be nice if I could set the path to the 3rd party dlls in the app.config.
I found this

`<probing privatePath="bin\DLLs" />`

but it seems to work for application subdirectories only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't hard code location for the DLLs. Put the directories into the %PATH% variable. Assuming Windows as environment read [Search path for loading DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d83bc18%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

EDIT:
%PATH% is an environment variable, so you can set it with [Environment.SetEnvironmentVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x.aspx). I would read privatePath from the configuration file, and use the given method to append it to %PATH%. Reading from the configuration file could be done with the [ConfigurationManager](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SystemConfiguration.aspx) class.

Comment: I am not hard-coding paths, as I mentioned.
How can I put my directory into the %PATH% variable during installation? I can't see any hint in the link you provided..
Can I specify the path in the app.config? That would be my preferred option.

Comment: I added a key to the <appSettings> in the app.config, which I read with the AppSettingsReader during application startup (in the Program.cs before Application.Run()) and append it to the PATH variable with EnvironmentSetEnvironmentVariable(). This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I will Write folloing command in your post build event (So you need not to do the manual work)

```
xcopy /s c:\source\your_dll_folder c:\your_target_folder\bin\debug
xcopy /s c:\source\your_dll_folder c:\your_target_folder\bin\Release
```

Here is post build event location properties of your project
[image]

Comment: Ok, I guess this works too, but I prefer the non-copying way by setting the PATH variable during startup. Thanks anyway :)